# ContinueDebugEvent results in crash in my debugger but not in x64dbg

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64

I made a small debugging application specifically to modify a protected executable, when using the application I can hand off the debugging by suspending the process then calling `DebugActiveProcessStop` and attaching x64dbg to the process and resuming.

The target I'm debugging performs a checksum on itself in 488 inlined places, with my debugging application I breakpoint all of these with a byte pattern search, when the breakpoint hits I intend to place a hardware breakpoint after the checksum command and then undo all of my memory modifications. When the hardware breakpoint hits I read some pertinent registers, store them in a file and patch that checksum to always pass without performing the checksum calculations the next time it is called.

The issue arrives that when I call `ContinueDebugEvent` from my debugger to get to the hardware breakpoint the target always crashes after a few steps with an access violation(c0000005). While testing things I found that if I suspend the process instead of calling `ContinueDebugEvent` and then pass the debugging over to x64dbg and let it `ContinueDebugEvent` the target runs fine. I debugged x64dbg with x64dbg to see what it's doing differently and the call it makes has what appears to be identical parameters to my call to `ContinueDebugEvent`, just the processId, the threadID, and 10002 (DBG_CONTINUE)

Does anyone know how/why the target would crash when both of our debuggers are making the same function call?

Comment: the `ContinueDebugEvent` call of course not leads to crash. it simply resume debugged process and let him continue execute. error in another place - say how you set thread context, handle another debug events, etc.